# Django: Hiding necessary forms on template page

Tags: css, django, html, django-forms

I have a Django application which takes the lat/lon from a user's coordinates via HTML5 geolocation and places these into form fields via jQuery. Markers are then placed on a map using these coordinates. This works very well.

The problem: I want to hide these forms so they're invisible to the user, but these still need to be "on the page" so they can receive the information. So excluding these via the Django forms file won't be acceptable.

I tried one method which hid the form field but left the form label. I'd like to hide the entire row from the user and remove the space where the form field exists while it still remains in the background to receive the info.

Is this possible? Not sure if it requires a CSS trick or a something built-in to Django.

Any help or insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your forms an ID and in CSS set `display: none` for these IDs. Alternatively, use a common class instead of separate IDs.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Django auto-generates the forms and the IDs are contained within a master div which is generically named the same as other divs. It only allowed hiding the field but left the name of the field. Good answer, though!